# Como agregar random items a una lista en python?

Tags: python, lista

Tengo un ejercicio en el cual se me presenta una lista .
Se me pide agregar 10 numeros random a esta usando la funcion randomint()
sin embargo no se como hacer para agregar 10 de estos numeros random a mi lista

```
import random

my_list = [4,5,734,43,45]
```

por ejemplo creo mi variable random asi:

```
random_number = random.randomint(0,99)
```

sin embargo no se como podria agregar con un loop 10 numeros random a mi lista.
La salida tiene que ser un nuevo array con 15 items. Intento con append pero no me funciona

Gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: sería bueno que mostraras qué has intentado exactamente. Por ejemplo lo de `append()` es correcto, ¿qué te da? En general, iría bien leer [ask] y dar un [mcve]

Comment: `my_list.append([random.randint(0,99) for _ in range(10)])`

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
my_list = [4,5,734,43,45] 
for i in range(10):
     my_list.append((random.randrange(5, 27, 4)))
my_list
```

ahi va, espero te sirva.

Comment: funcionó ok en este entorno virtual: https://onlinegdb.com/HydMadVyP ahí está corriendo sin problemas.